# Custom post type term names with ampersand in the term name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta, terms

Every time I think I've got a handle on WordPress it finds a way to baffle me.  Recently we've been having an issue with not being able to attach term names with an & (ampersand) character in the term name.  After some googling I'm finding that it's because it's stored in the database as an encoded entity `&amp;` and whatever WordPress uses to search for the term doesn't automatically encode it.  Here is my taxonomy definition:

```
    private static function _register_bunnies() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Bunnies'),
            'singular_name' => __('Bunny'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Bunnies'),
            'popular_items' => null,
            'all_items' => __('All Bunnies'),
            'parent_item' => __('Parent Bunny'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Bunny:' ),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Bunny'),
            'view_item' => __('View Bunny'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Bunny'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Bunny'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Bunny Name'),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => null,
            'add_or_remove_items' => null,
            'choose_from_most_used' => null,
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'animals/bunny'),
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => null,
            'show_ui' => true,
        );

        register_taxonomy('animal-bunny', null, $args);
    }
```

WordPress appears to be automatically attaching the animals-bunny to a post when one is provided.  The only "fix" I could come up with was the following:

```
    add_action( 'update_post_meta', 'my_update_post_meta', 10, 4);
    function my_update_post_meta($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
        if (isset($_POST['tax_input']['animal-bunny'])) {
            $_POST['tax_input']['animal-bunny'] = htmlentities($_POST['tax_input']['animal-bunny']);
        }
    }
```

With this WordPress can find the correct term in the database but this seems like a horribly hack of a way to do this.  Can someone point me at the correct way to fix this problem?

Comment: It took me a minute to understand what you were asking. Just to clarify, `$_POST['tax_input']['animal-bunny']` holds a term with an `&` in it and you're having trouble searching on it because of the `&`? Does that input hold the term slug or name ( I'm assuming name ).

Comment: When I try to attach a term to a custom post type where the term name includes an ampersand WordPress finds the term fine (when doing the type ahead search) but because WP is not turning the & into &amp; it never finds the term in the database when trying to attach it to the post.  So I add the term in the admin edit post screen and hit update post and the post never has the term I just tried to attach when it finishes.  The code I provided fixes it but I can't believe that's a proper fix.  It holds the term name.  Thank you!

Comment: WordPress will convert terms htmlentities `&` to `&amp;` when creating a terms either through the metabox or from the category page. Unless you're running an older version of WordPress ( I can't imagine older versions didn't do this though ). If your install isn't doing this, something went wrong elsewhere - the registration is fine. Maybe disable plugins?

Comment: I've just tried to create the post tag with the name "Test&test", all seems ok but if I try to search "test&test" (using search box in edit-tags.php screen) it doesn't return any results. The name in the databse is "Test&amp;test" and the slug "test-test". I think we can do very little to help you here, [you could open a ticket in core trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/). I've tried also creating a post with the title "Test&test" and this issue doesn't happen as the post title is stored in database exactly as "Test&test" (slug for this post is testtest).